# Create a shell script via command line

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

How to create `script.sh` file at Ubuntu with the commands below. The script must contains commands in a syntax exactly as it is, with `$` signs as variables and quotations as in below:

```bash
paths=($(ls -l /home/*/.bashrc | awk "{print \$NF}")); echo "${paths[@]}"

for path in "${paths[@]}"
do
    sudo sh -c "echo 'if [ -z \"\$HISTTIMEFORMAT\" ]
    then export HISTTIMEFORMAT=\"%F %T \"
    fi' >> "$path""
done
```

I know how to create an empty file and use `nano script.sh` and manually paste the text, but I need this to be automated. I am struggling to pass the text with all symbols etc.

Something like below, but it fails:

```bash
sudo bash -c 'echo "#!/bin/bash
paths=(\$(ls -l /home/*/.bashrc | awk \"{print \$NF}\")); echo \"\${paths[@]}\";
for path in \"\${paths[@]}\"
do
    sudo sh -c "echo 'if [ -z \"\$HISTTIMEFORMAT\" ]
    then export HISTTIMEFORMAT=\"%F %T \"
    fi' >> "$path""
done
" > /etc/temp/script.sh'
```

Comment: `The script must contains commands in a syntax exactly as it is`. I would not as this syntax is invalid bad practice to begin with.

Comment: @LéaGris Any suggestions how to copy those commands into a shell script via terminal commands, not opening editor?

Comment: Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: btw, `paths=( $(...anything...) )` runs afoul of [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29), and using `ls` runs afoul of [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: In general, defining a function and then using `declare -f` to serialize it is a _vastly_ less failure-prone way to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Nothing to do with *how* to edit each file, but *why* are you editing each user's own shell configuration like this? Ubuntu's `bash` sources `/etc/bash.bashrc` before `~/.bashrc`; just add `export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "` to that file, and users that want to can override the value in their own `.bashrc`.

Comment: In your first attempt, the opening double quote right before `echo`  gets clost just before `$path` (because the quotes in between are escaped. Please fix your quoting. BTW, if you want to pass the `$` literally, consider to use a single-quoted here-document instead of fiddling with double quotes and escaping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it like this:

```bash
sudo tee -a /home/*/.bashrc > /dev/null << 'EOF'
if [ -z "$HISTTIMEFORMAT" ]
then export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T'
fi
EOF
```

Comment: So it does exactly the same - checks and updated each current user `.bashrc` file?

Comment: @Mund exactly the same, will append to each /home/user/.bashrc file